# Azure CI Pipeline YAML for Specflow Integration

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, continuous-integration, specflow

I am trying to configure my spec flow project with the Azure CI pipeline. When I try to create Specflow+LivingDoc with TestExecution.json, the pipeline is unable to find the path. Attaching my YAML, and specflow.json along with this. Can anybody help me with this??

```
YAML

- task: SpecFlowPlus@0
  displayName: 'Upload SpecFlow Living Docs'
  inputs:
    projectFilePath: 'MyProjecct'
    projectName: 'MyProjecct'
    testExecutionJson: '**\TestExecution.json'
    projectLanguage: 'en'
```

```
specflow.json

{
    "livingDocGenerator": {
      "enabled": true,
      "filePath": "{CurrentDirectory}\\TestResults\\TestExecution.json"
    }
  }
```

Error
[image]

```
Error

##[error]Error: Command failed: dotnet D:\a_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.859\CLI\LivingDoc.CLI.dll feature-folder "D:\a\1\s\MyProjecct" --output-type JSON --test-execution-json "**/TestExecution.json" --output "D:\a\1\s\16707\FeatureData.json" --project-name "MyProjecct" --project-language "en"
```

Comment: Please post the whole error message

Comment: ##[error]Error: Command failed: dotnet D:\a\_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.859\CLI\LivingDoc.CLI.dll feature-folder "D:\a\1\s\MyProjecct" --output-type JSON --test-execution-json "**/TestExecution.json" --output "D:\a\1\s\16707\FeatureData.json" --project-name "MyProjecct" --project-language "en"

Comment: Is the file generated in the specified folder?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message as plain text. It is too hard to read on a comment.

Comment: @AndreasWillich Yes. WHile tested in local machine,the file has been generated. But in CI pipeline the above shown error is coming

Comment: Is there a task before this one that creates the TestExecution.json file? Maybe a different pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I tried to configure this a few days back.

Try giving the full path to your TestExecution.json, that should work. The pattern matching is not working in the file paths so provide full path to your json files as well as project/test assembly etc...

Answer (score 0):

Before the SpecFlowPlus task you can add a shell task (such as Bask) to execute the `ls` command to see if the `TestExecution.json` file has been generated or existing in the specified Feature folder under current directory.

```
ls -R
```

If the `TestExecution.json` file is not existing, you should go to check if there is any issue on the step that generates this file.

Comment: I tried to generate specflow living doc in my local machine and it is working as expected. But when comes to CI pipeline, when it tries to execute textExecutionjsonPath, the command getting failed